# Oracle 11g VARRAY of OBJECTS

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have the following statements in Oracle 11g:

```
CREATE TYPE person AS OBJECT (
    name VARCHAR2(10),
    age NUMBER
);

CREATE TYPE person_varray AS VARRAY(5) OF person;

CREATE TABLE people (
    somePeople person_varray
)
```

How can i select the name value for a person i.e.

```
SELECT somePeople(person(name)) FROM people
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that:

1. What you're doing isn't what I'd be doing.  It sort of completely violates relational principles, and you're going to end up with an object/type system in Oracle that you might not be able to change once it's been laid down.  The best use I've seen for SQL TYPEs (not PL/SQL types) is basically being able to cast a ref cursor back for pipelined functions.
2. You have to unnest the collection before you can query it relationally, like so:

   SELECT NAME FROM 
   (SELECT SP.* FROM PEOPLE P, TABLE(P.SOME_PEOPLE) SP)

That'll give you all rows, because there's nothing in your specifications (like a PERSON_ID attribute) to restrict the rows.

The Oracle Application Developer's Guide - Object Relational Features discusses all of this in much greater depth, with examples.

Comment: what is the difference between a SQL TYPE and a PL/SQL type?

Answer (score 0):

```
To insert query:-

insert into people values (
person_varray(person('Ram','24'))
);

To select :-

select * from people;

SELECT NAME FROM (SELECT SP.* FROM PEOPLE P, TABLE(P.somePeople) SP)

While inserting a row into people table use constructor of 
person_varray and then the constructor 
of person type for each project.
The above INSERT command 
creates a single row in people table.

 select somePeople from people ;

 person(NAME, age) 
---------------------------------------------------
person_varray(person('Ram', 1), 

To update the  query will be:-

update people 
set somePeople =  
           person_varray 
           (  
               person('SaAM','23')  
           )
```